# How to get and Insert data in JSON Parsing in IOS6

Tags: json, ios6, iphone-5

How to get and Insert data in JSON Parsing in IOS6

I am trying to insert data in to JSON link and retrieve data from JSON link by using JSONParser.

How can I use JSON Parser without adding JSON frame work in IOS6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to Import JSON Files you'll get that from [here](https://github.com/groopd/SBJSON-library/tree/master/JSON)

Then if you are using POST method then do Following :

```
NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"u=%@&p= %@",strUname,strPassword];
myRequestString=[myRequestString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[myRequestString UTF8String] length:[myRequestString length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"Your Webservice URL"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:myRequestData];

NSData *returnData = nil;
returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
NSDictionary *myDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
```

If You are using GET method then use the Following :

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your WebService with Parameters in URL"]]];
NSDictionary *MyDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
```

Hope This will Help.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "without adding JSON framework"? Does it mean that you want to parse JSON by yourself? Why do you wish to reinvent the wheel when there exist good libraries?

I recommend [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit), a fast and well written Objective-C library. Just two files you include in your project and you can parse and serialize data from and into JSON.

If you wish to learn JSON and would like to create your own library for learning purposes, first read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) to learn what JSON is and what its syntax is. From here you can think how to implement a dictionary to JSON (or even object to JSON).

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *Post=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&username=%@&password=%@",,Text_Email.text,Text_User.text,Text_Password.text];
NSData *PostData = [Post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSString *PostLengh=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[Post length]];
NSURL *Url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@usersignup.php",ServerPath]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:Url     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0]; 
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:PostLengh forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Lenght"];
[request setHTTPBody:PostData];

NSData *ReturnData =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:Nil error:Nil];     
NSString *Response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:ReturnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];     
Response = [Response stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. You should comment your code and explains the steps instead of just pasting a bunch of code. Thanks!